# Select SUM and Calculate Percentage per row

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update

How do I select the SUM of all the values from C1, and then `UPDATE` the values of C2 as percentage per row

```
C2 = C1 / SUM(C1)

+----+-------+
| C1 |   C2  |
+----+-------+
|  1 |   2%  |
|  2 |   5%  |
|  3 |   8%  |
|  4 |   11% |
|  5 |   13% |
|  6 |   16% |
|  7 |   19% |
|  8 |   22% |
+----+-------+
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Cross join the table to the sum of column c1:

```
update tablename t cross join (
  select sum(c1) total from tablename  
) s
set t.c2 = concat(floor(100.0 * t.c1 / s.total), '%');
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/hAD2ceRhEPQ5A2gKW5MHxG/0).
Results:

```
| c1  | c2  |
| --- | --- |
| 1   | 2%  |
| 2   | 5%  |
| 3   | 8%  |
| 4   | 11% |
| 5   | 13% |
| 6   | 16% |
| 7   | 19% |
| 8   | 22% |
```

Comment: very nice solution, even removing `cross` keyword gives the same result.

Comment: A join without the ON condition is a cross join also.

Comment: well :) I meant just keyword is redundant.

Comment: It is, but I prefer explicit definitions.